# What image size in photoshop should I create for website background

Tags: html, css, photoshop

If I want to design a background for a website using photoshop, what image size should I make ? I want to make a gradient background for my web-app but I don't the specifications to follow.

Comment: If it's just a simple gradient you may be better off creating the background with css3 gradients. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Put Photoshop down, take our your CSS3 tool and begin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [w3schools - css - background](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).  You need to use background-repeat, otherwise you will be forcing the users to download a huge image.  So make your gradient of any size, then crop a piece off that is the same height, but a small width (< 10 pixels).  Use this as your background with the css `background-repeat: repeat-x;`.

Comment: and how to check if it less than 10 pixels ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Patterns or Gradients for a good look on all screen resolutions and then, in CSS use

```
background-repeat:repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the background's width to 5px and the height very long, and set your css to `background-reapeat: repeat-x; background: url(your image url here) fixed` This is if you have a vertical gradient, if you have a  horizontal gradient, it is just vice-versa.